# SKSpriteKit remove node stored in array

Tags: swift, skspritenode

So I have an array holding references to all my tiles in the game, and on a click I want to loop through and destroy any tiles that are adjacent to one another. I already have a function that checks for adjacent tiles and stores which ones should be deleted in my checkedTiles array of Bools. I then want to loop through this array and delete any nodes from my blocks array(which holds the references to the tiles) where checkedTiles is true. I thought this would work but blocks[col][row].removeFromParent() doesn't actually remove the node. Any ideas/suggestions for accomplishing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

--blocks and checkedTiles are initialized elsewhere in the program.

```
var blocks: Array<Array<SKSpriteNode>> = []
var checkedTiles: Array<Array<Bool>> = []

for col in 0..<numCols {
    for row in 0..<numRows {
        if checkedTiles[col][row] == true {
            print("removing tile")
            blocks[col][row].removeFromParent()
            checkedTiles[col][row] = false

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried you code and it works for me. I can show you an example, but you should probably just  print checkedTiles before you use it, to make sure that everything is okay. By the way, do you see "removing title" at all, or it is not printed ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workable example, you can just copy and paste it to see how it works. This is how you should do it. I suspect that the problem is with your `checkedTiles` variable. Try to print it out before you use it and see if everything is okay there.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        var blocks: [[SKSpriteNode]] = []

        //make a 3x3 matrix of SKSpriteNodes
        for  i in 0..<3 {

            var row = [SKSpriteNode]()

            for  j in 0..<3 {

                let node = SKSpriteNode(color: .purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
                node.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX + CGFloat(i * 30 ), y: frame.midY - CGFloat(j * 30 ))
                row.append(node)
                addChild(node)
            }
            blocks.append(row)
        }

        //Just remove the tile placed in the middle of the all tiles

        var checkedTiles: [[Bool]] = [
            [false,false, false],
            [false, true, false],
            [false, false, false]
        ]

        print(checkedTiles)

        for col in 0..<3 {
            for row in 0..<3 {
                if checkedTiles[col][row] == true {
                    print("removing tile")
                    blocks[col][row].removeFromParent()
                    checkedTiles[col][row] = false   
                }
            }
        }
        print(checkedTiles)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do see "removing tile" getting printed and have also printed out the row and column to confirm that the correct tile is getting removed, so I don't believe the issue is related to checkedTiles array. Could it be something weird with the dot operator? If I do print(blocks[col][row]) and then blocks[col][row].removeFromParent() and then print(blocks[col][row]) I still get the same output from the second print statement as the first which comes before the removefromParent() call

Comment: @user2975241 Note that removing the node from its parent will not remove it from blocks array. Still, it should remove the node from the scene (or whatever block's parent is).